# Categories lose hierarchy order once assigned to post

Tags: categories, widgets, hierarchical

I setup some hierarchical categories and when I assign them to a post the widget reflows and loses the hierarchy display. Example:

```
- Education Services
-- Arts & Archives
--- Fine Arts
-- Reference
-- Health Sciences
```

When selecting "Education Services" & "Reference" (marked with 'x') the widget appears like this:

```
x Education Services
-x Reference
- Arts & Archives
-- Fine Arts
- Health Sciences
```

So since the selected (top-level) parent goes to the top, all children besides the selected one look they have lost their parent (even though they actually have not).

I have read some other forums post/support tickets but not much about this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused about what's happening. Can you post some of the code or a link to the site? What widget are you referring to?

Comment: if you are still curious see the Trac reports t31os linked below.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! When you said 'widget' I assumed you were talking about how the categories display on the front end. I'm with you - that's a very annoying 'feature'. I've had clients complain in the past and never knew how to describe what was happening much less fix it. Great question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out Scribu's plugin, i believe this addresses the very problem you're describing which has been reported on Trac a handful of times(but closed/deleted).

**Category Checklist Tree** by scribu
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/

**Related tickets:**

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14723
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10982

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: thanks. i saw various forums posts that were closed/un-answered also. i will give this plugin a shot or just end up re-working my idea i suppose.

Comment: If necessary you can always unregister the metabox and create your own that sorts them differently(if you're into doing that). :)

Comment: The "Category Checklist Tree" plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported. Please consider using this new plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-in-hierarchical-order/ as a replacement.

Comment: I can confirm that "Categories in Hierarchical Order" works and has been tested with WordPress v 5.2.2. Thank you for the note Guicara!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the plugins [Category Checklist Tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-checklist-tree/) and [Categories in Hierarchical Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-in-hierarchical-order/), you could directly use this filter in your `function.php` file without adding any plugin:

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', function($args, $idPost) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;

    return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```

It is also possible to apply this filter only to a specific taxonomies:

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', function($args, $idPost) {
    $taxonomies = ['foo', 'bar'];

    if (isset($args['taxonomy']) && in_array($args['taxonomy'], $taxonomies)) {
        $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Doesn't work as of WP Version 5.2.2

Comment: Works for me in WP 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a plugin that solves this problem. Besides preserving the hierarchy of categories, this plugin adds a toggle style the category tree.

See the official plugin page: 
http://www.rafaelmarques.com/wordpress/plugins/wp-best-tree/